# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 33)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I started running dukkakc's code about DeepSuccinySite and i have a problem. The result show: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 33). I've been searching for the error for a long time but to no avail. Can someone help me?

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from Bio import SeqIO
from numpy import array
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, classification_report
from keras.models import load_model

r_test_x = []
r_test_y = []
posit_1 = 1;
negat_0 = 0;
win_size = 33 # actual window size
win_size_kernel = int(win_size/2 + 1)

# define universe of possible input values
alphabet = 'ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYV-'
# define a mapping of chars to integers
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))

#-------------------------TEST DATASET----------------------------------------
#for positive sequence
def innertest1():
#Input
data = seq_record.seq
#rint(data) 
# integer encode input data
for char in data:
    if char not in alphabet:
        return
integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in data]
r_test_x.append(integer_encoded)
r_test_y.append(posit_1)
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("test_positive_sites.fasta", "fasta"):
innertest1()
#for negative sequence
def innertest2():
#Input
data = seq_record.seq
#print(data) 
# integer encode input data
for char in data:
    if char not in alphabet:
        return
integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in data]
r_test_x.append(integer_encoded)
r_test_y.append(negat_0)
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("test_negative_sites.fasta", "fasta"):
innertest2()
# Changing to array (matrix)    
r_test_x = array(r_test_x)
r_test_y = array(r_test_y)

# Balancing test dataset
# Testing Data Balancing by undersampling####################################
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=7)
x_res3, y_res3 = rus.fit_resample(r_test_x, r_test_y)
#Shuffling
r_test_x, r_test_y = shuffle(x_res3, y_res3, random_state=7)
r_test_x = np.array(r_test_x)
r_test_y = np.array(r_test_y)
############################################################################

##LOAD MODEL####
model = load_model('model.h5')
#print("This is final ",model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][16])
r_test_y_2 = keras.utils.to_categorical(r_test_y, 2)
score = model.evaluate(r_test_x, r_test_y_2, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
Y_pred = model.predict(r_test_x)
Y_pred = (Y_pred > 0.5)
y_pred1 = [np.argmax(y, axis=None, out=None) for y in Y_pred]
y_pred1 = np.array(y_pred1)

print("Matthews Correlation : ",matthews_corrcoef(r_test_y, y_pred1))
print("Confusion Matrix : \n",confusion_matrix(r_test_y, y_pred1))
# ROC

fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(r_test_y, y_pred1)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print("AUC : ", roc_auc)
print(classification_report(r_test_y, y_pred1))

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Does the error occur at `score = model.evaluate` ? If yes check `r_test_x` shape. It should be (len, 256, 256, 3) if not that's where your error is coming from.

Comment: yes, it is. But i don't know how to change the shape

Comment: if you're working with numpy array you can call the `reshape()` method on your `r_test_x` to have the right shape.

Comment: i changed but it doesn't work. Can you make it clear please?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your input has to match the expected format of the input layer of your model.
You can use `reshape` to get the right format, expected the dimension match, otherwise you'll need to pad the missing dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(16,1,1)
A.shape
  (16,1,1)

B = A.reshape([4,4,1,1]
B.shape
  (4,4,1,1)
```